# How to add a single row below the header in pivot widget in Sisense

Tags: sisense

I was working with the pivot widget in my dashboard and I needed to add a row right below the header like a description.It should be above the table content which should appear right below the header and it should be shown in the export as well. I tried using JS also but I couldn't get it to work. I have attached an image below for reference. Any help is much appreciated.

I tried using javascript to manually add a row by using the **append()** function but no luck so far.

Thank you.

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us4eI.png)